# How to put python and pygame on a flash drive?

Tags: python, pygame

So I need to be able to bring python to and from my school, and I figured the easiest way would be to put all of it on one flash drive. I would download everything onto the laptop the school gave us but I don't think they would like me downloading things onto their computers.

I'm not sure how to go about putting python on a flash drive so if anyone knows how, then it would help a lot.

Comment: If you are learning Python at your school I don't see how they can deny you downloading it.

Comment: The project isn't specifically about coding. You choose something you're interested in, then research it, present the idea for a final project, then actually do the final project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should search for 'portable python'. Following are some common options:

https://winpython.github.io/#portable

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

https://github.com/cloudmatrix/myppy

See http://pythonforengineers.com/3-and-12-ways-to-try-python-without-installing-it/ for some other options.

However, I do not think school will mind you putting python on laptop. It will be an asset if properly installed. If needed, you can yourself remove it before returning laptop to school. Even if you cannot do that, school computer department should be able to format the laptop and reinstall the system, if required, though most likely they will install python on all laptops!

Comment: So installed winpython (I need to get a bigger flash drive though) and so how do I get pygame on to it as well?

Comment: check pip utility for winpython: eg: `pip install pygame`

Comment: The school gives us Chromebooks and I'm not sure how to do that on the school chromebooks. At this point I might just ask the whoever is in charge of the chromebooks and see if I can just download python

Comment: That, as I wrote above, will be best option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) to create a portable install of Python on your flash drive, and then copy the Pygame files onto the flash drive as well.